# How to handle Python format errors in log message template?

Tags: python, templates, logging, format

I sometimes mess up the format in template strings for Python's `logging` module, for example:

```py
import logging
logging.warning('%d', 1, 2)  # BROKEN
```

In the console I can see a warning message (stack trace omitted):

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1034, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File ".../python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 880, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File ".../python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 619, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File ".../python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 380, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
    ...
Message: '%d'
Arguments: (1, 2)
```

However, neither my message nor this warning is sent to the log handler that would actually write it to a log file, send it to logstash etc.

I know that I can find these bugs with [pylint](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html) using logging-too-few-args (E1206) and logging-too-many-args (E1205) however I still would prefer some kind of runtime fallback in case one of them slips through.

So unless one monitors stderr from outside of Python these kind of bugs are easy to overlook.

Is there a way to still log a message with a marker and the essentials parts, for example:

> [LogBug] message='%d', arguments=(1, 2)

That way, the original information would still be preserved and one could periodically scan log files for the `[LogBug]` marker.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `try`/`except`, maybe? Possibly using `re` to extract the message and arguments from the exception message

```
import re

try:
    logging.warning('%d', 1, 2)
except TypeError as e:
    message = re.search(r'Message: ([^\n]*)[\n$]', e.message).group(1)
    arguments = re.search(r'Arguments: ([^\n]*)[\n$]', e.message).group(1)
    logging.error("[LogBug] message=%s, arguments=%s",message, arguments)
    # if you want, you could re-raise this exception
```

If you do go with this solution you might also have to accommodate for error handling in case the `TypeError` isn't quite in the format you expect and thus the regex won't work and will raise an `AttributeError` when you try to call `.group()` on it.

There's no limit to how deep you could go with this, potentially, but if you make *really really sure* that this check works properly then it might be able to catch the others.

---

Alternatively, instead of trusting the `logging` package to do argument insertion, if you're using a recent version of python you could use format strings instead, which leaves no room for that kind of ambiguity:

```
i, j = 1, 2
logging.warning(f"{i}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Concerning `try/except`: `logging.warning` does not `raise` the exception to the caller but handles it internally and logs to `stderr`. The caller does not know that the logging failed. Concerning using f-strings: this is discouraged because it renders the log message even if it does not have to be logged thus wasting CPU and causing memory activity.